# Do you keep tribal XP / bonus between Nether tribes?

Tags: nether

If you select a tribe in Nether then the general XP you earn contributes towards how well that tribe likes you increasing how well you are known.  If you go to Lake Side and switch tribes does this level reset?  If not does the bonus reset?

For example, I'm in STKR and I'm Well Known so I get a 10% XP bonus for any XP I get.  If I joined H.O.P.E would I still get 10% for tasks such as package delivery, or repairing Anti-Nether Devices?  I know I wouldn't for general XP such as killing a Nether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you go to Lake Side and switch tribes does this level reset?

If you mean the tribe status, **no**. You're still the same level with that tribe. This does mean if you're STKR and switch to HOPE, and you meet a guy who's in STKR and you kill him you get -xp from STKR, but if he kills you, he gets no -XP on STKR but instead he gets -xp on HOPE

> I'm in STKR and I'm Well Known so I get a 10% XP bonus for any XP I get. If I joined H.O.P.E would I still get 10% for tasks such as package delivery, or repairing Anti-Nether Devices?

No. The XP bonus depends on your **current** tribe experience.